# Navigator.of(context).pop() not working properly

Tags: flutter

I've been longing to ask this a while now but I thought of first trying to find a solution myself which apparently failed. Every time I try doing Navigator.of(context).pop() to go back to the previous page that I navigated from, I end up getting a black screen instead. I wonder what I'm doing wrong and how this can be fixed? The code and the screenshots are given below:

This is the screen that I intend to Navigate from. The aim is to go to the Cart Screen and back. Clicking on the Add to Cart button takes us to the Cart Screen(For obvious reasons, I had to conceal everything. Apologies in advance)

[image]

This is the Cart Screen. Clicking the back button should take us back to the previous screen.

[image]

I get a black screen instead of navigating back to where I came from.

[image]

The code is as follows:
This is the code snippet from the screen that has the Add To Cart button on it which navigates to the Cart Screen.

```
InkWell(
          onTap: () =>
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/cart-screen'),   //Route for the Cart Screen
          child: Container(
            width: width * 0.5,
            height: height * 0.06,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color.fromRGBO(168, 236, 38, 1),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                      spreadRadius: 2,
                      blurRadius: 5,
                      offset: Offset(1, 2))
                ]),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Add To Cart',
                textScaleFactor: textScale,
                style:
                    const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

The Cart Screen Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  CartScreenState createState() => CartScreenState();
}

class CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final textScale = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor * 1.2;

    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: InkWell(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),     //The pop method
            child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.red)),
        title: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.26),
          child: Text(
            'Cart',
            textScaleFactor: textScale,
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have used "pushReplacementNamed" which removes the history behind... when you try to go back... there's nothing to go back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use push instead of pushReplacement. pushReplacement replaces the first screen so when you try to pop back, there's nothing there.

Bonus Tip: You can use the [BackButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BackButton-class.html) widget instead of creating your own with an InkWell.